# magneto 2 migration tool installation error

Tags: soap, migration, magento2

time of installing migration tool in magento2.2.7 getting error "vertex/sdk 1.0.0 requires ext-soap * -> the requested PHP extension soap is missing from your system". But soap is already installed and enabled.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check in your **php.ini** file. under your lampp folder

   Search like php_soap.dll, each dll extension
2. r**emoving the first ; character**,  like this

   extension=php_soap.dll
3. Now restart the apache server